# Dynamically pick first screen for cordova application with Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, cordova-3

I am developing an application with cordova 3.50 and jquery mobile. I want to load the first  page depending on whether the user is logged in or not. 
This is the behavior i desire:

1. After the splash screen if the user is already logged in i want the home page to appear.
2. After the splash screen if the user is not logged in i want the login screen to appear

Is there anyway i can configure this (deciding which page to display) in JQM or using javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;

$("#start").on('pageinit', function() {

if(loggedin)
changePage("pages/home.html");


  else
    changePage("pages/login.html");

    });

});
    function changePage(page_id){

    $.mobile.changePage(page_id, {transition: "flow", changeHash: false});
    }
```

where #start is the id of the index.html, loaded as the first page of phonegap
and loggedin is the var which holds boolean value